# Debug Assertion Failed C++ Forward List Merge

Tags: c++

Hi I am using the forward list STL library in VS 2019. This is my block of code:

```
forward_list<int> fl1;
    fl1.assign({ 1,2,3,4 });
    fl1.push_front(0);
    fl1.pop_front();
    cout << "Front " << fl1.front() << endl;
    forward_list<int>::iterator it4 = fl1.begin();
    it4 = fl1.insert_after(it4, 5);
    fl1.emplace_front(6);
    fl1.remove(6);
    forward_list<int> fl2;
    fl2.assign({ 9,8,7,6,6 });
    fl2.unique();
    fl2.sort();
    fl1.sort();
    fl2.reverse();
    fl1.merge(fl2);
   // fl1.clear();

    for (int i : fl1)
        cout << i << endl;
```

Once the program hits the merge line, it gives me a **"Debug Assertion Failed Line: 1492 Expression: Sequence not ordered"** my code is only 500 lines long and the code itself occurs at line 342 where I have that for loop that is supposed to handle iterate through fl1: for (int i : fl1)
            cout << i << endl;

When I hit abort and see the debug error, it says "**Unhandled exception at 0x5049F2F6 (ucrtbased.dll) in Derektut.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal"**

Why is this?

Comment: To use `merge()`, the lists need to be sorted, and your `fl1` list is not sorted.  [See the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/merge)

Comment: So i added that sort command and it still gave me the same error @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: You should post a [mcve].  First, the `sort` function sorts in ascending order, and your other list has descending sort order.  How is that going to work?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I actually had that sort command initially but took it off from my post because when I checked it wasn't the solution so I just took it off. That was the very first thing I checked

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I see now. The tutor didn't even go over this. He ran his code with the expressions as they were and had no issues.  That's why I was confused. Thanks, removing the reverse function fixed it !

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie when he ran his code, the forward lists were merged and the first list was not even ordered. He is not using VS 2019. SO I have no idea how he can get away with that and I can't

Comment: If the lists are not sorted, the behavior is undefined, meaning anything can happen, including "work".  So your tutor's code is wrong, but they didn't know it since the compiler's runtime didn't check, and is not required to check.  The Visual Studio debug runtime library will actually check if the lists are sorted, and will assert if the lists are not sorted.  Now run your code in "Release" mode under Visual Studio -- do you see an error?  If not, then that's the issue your tutor was dealing with -- bad code, but no indication the code was bad.

Answer (score 0):

The [std::forward_list::merge](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/merge) requires that both lists are sorted.  Your `fl1` list is not sorted when `fl1.merge()` is called.  Calling `merge` on an unsorted list is undefined behavior.

As to the **Debug Assertion** error:

Since this is a Visual Studio generated error, in Visual Studio, the debug runtime will check if both lists are sorted when making the call to `merge`, and will `assert()` if one of the lists is not sorted.